# Swiftmailer send e-mail fails

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I have this code which I am using to send an email via Swiftmailer.
I tried many things, I tried with Phpmailer aswell and I am not able to send a simple e-mail. I also tried with mail() function in php and nothing, I don't have the sendmail configured, so I thought to use one of these libraries.

The code I am using is:

```
 require_once ('lib/swift_required.php');
 $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
  //Give the message a subject
  ->setSubject('Webinar Registration')
  //Set the From address with an associative array
  ->setFrom(array('ami@am.com' => 'FROM NAME'))
  //Set the To addresses with an associative array
  ->setTo(array('ami@am.com'))
  //Give it a body
  ->setBody('My Message')
  //And optionally an alternative body
  //->addPart('<q>Here is the message itself</q>', 'text/html')
  ;

//Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('127.0.0.1', 25);
//Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

//Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

When I debug it, it stops right after the require statement. I am trying to send it via localhost and i don't want to use smtp.
Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an SMTP server setup on 127.0.0.1?

Comment: I have set up an SMPT account in IIS manager @webnoob